# Joe Blow Pump Maintenance

Tags: maintenance, pump

My Top Peak Joe Blow floor pump has been getting harder and harder to pump. I bought the high end model so that my 94 lb wife could pump up her own tires, but it has gotten to the point where I can barely get my own tires to 110 psi.

Is there some maintenance that I'm supposed to be doing on the pump?

I found a [rebuild kit online](http://www.jensonusa.com/!wea1iMPJxTVN0QwS4!Doiw!/Topeak-Rebuild-Kit-For-Joe-Blow), is that the ticket to making it work better?

Comment: I've got one and sometimes find it harder to pump than other times, but I reattach the value and it works fine. How old is yours? Does it get a lot of use? Does it move easily when not attached to the inner tube? and finally, does it make any strange sounds?

Comment: I think it is about 2 years old and it gets used 4+ times a week. The part that hooks to the valve doesn't move easier. I think it squeaks when you use it.

Comment: I don't see how you could lose with that rebuild kit (though it would better if it included a small tube of silicone lube).  The round piece in the middle is an O ring that is probably the "leather" for the main cylinder.  This would be available from any hardware store.  The parts on the right replace the gasket in the chuck.  Not entirely sure about the parts on the left.

Answer (score 3):

What precisely is wrong with it?  If it's got high friction when you work the pump without it connected then working the right kind of lube into the cylinder would do the trick.  (Not sure what the "right kind" would be, but definitely NOT regular oil.  Probably either a glycerine product or a silicone product.)

If it's leaking air back through the cylinder then lube might help, or you may need a new "leather" (which is no doubt plastic/rubber).

If it's leaking through the "chuck" that fits on the stem then some lube there may help, or a new gasket.

Comment: There are no leaks.

Comment: So it's just friction?  Get some silicone lube valve from a hardware store.  Take apart the pump and spread a little lube on the moving parts.